# Activity restart when the View Mode is changed

Tags: android, emulation

I need a little help in View modes.
. 
After launching my Activity, when i press CTL+11 to change view mode from Portrait to Landscape. all activites are called again and they are restarted. A few dialogs are shown again.

Similar behaviour is seen when i change from Landscape to Portrait.

What do i need to do that my main activity does not start again when i change the orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add following property in androidmenifest.xml under activity tag.... 
" android:configChanges="orientation" "

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is standard behavior in android.

If you don't want this behavior, do this in your manifest-file:

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"/>
```